# Annotating text with NER: Exception: couldn't read TokensRegexNER

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to annotate text with Stanford CoreNLP v3.9.1 in Java.
The annotators used are : tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner

I've included the model jar from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html.
Both english models are included in my project (normal + kbp).

However, after loading the `english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz` classifier, the following exception is thrown: `Couldn't read TokensRegexNER from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab`.

After opening the download jar model `stanford-english-kbp-corenlp-2018-02-27-models.jar`, the correct path to `regexner_caseless.tab` is `edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/regexner_caseless.tab` (notice the `english` subpath).

How do I make Stanford CoreNLP use the correct path?

Comment: How did you solve your problem please elaborate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the main models jar that comes with the distribution.

`stanford-corenlp-2018-02-27-models.jar`